# Congratulations Raffzahn!

Tags: discussion

Massive congratulations to [@raffzahn](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/6659/raffzahn) for cracking 200k! That's huge accomplishment, and a clear demonstration of Raffzahn's considerable contributions to the site.

Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 13):

Thanks.

I'm the literal guy standing on shoulders of many, as my output would be way less useful/readable without the continued support of all of you in checking (*1), correcting and improving.

Thank you very much to each and everyone here.

---

*1 - Not least by spell-checking.

Comment: When you mentioned that you are the "literal guy standing on the shoulders of many", some unique acrobatic imagery came to mind.  I don't think "literal" is the word you want for that sentence.  Unless you are literally standing on the shoulders of others, of course.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I go with that image - and if you'd know my weight, you'll agree that it takes more than one :)

Comment: Especially with your photo, I like the image.  Thank you for the smile today. :)